Bad Request : Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header
I have written the .Net API code to upload the file to One drive,
But continuously I am facing the issue "Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header." even If I have changed the content type to JSON.
Please help.
Controller code
 [HttpPost("upload")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> UploadToOneDrive([FromForm] IFormFile file)
 {
     if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
         return BadRequest("File not selected");

     using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
     {
         var fileName = file.FileName;
         var folderName = "https://springernature-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/personal/mbu4174_springernature_com/Documents/PicScout";
         var UserId = "mahesh.Borhade@springernature.com";
         await _graphService.UploadFileToOneDriveAsync(stream, UserId, folderName, fileName);
     }

     return Ok("File uploaded successfully");
 }

Service Code
  private void InitializeGraphClient()
  {
      var tenantId = _configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
      var clientId = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
      var clientSecret = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];

      // Use Azure.Identity's ClientSecretCredential for authentication
      var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

      _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);
  }

  public async Task UploadFileToOneDriveAsync(Stream fileStream, string UserId, string folderName, string fileName)
  {
      var uploadPath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName) ? $"/{fileName}" : $"/{folderName}/{fileName}";
      try 
      {
          await _graphClient.Users[UserId].Drive.Items["root"]
              .ItemWithPath(uploadPath)
              .Content
              .Request()
              .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
      }
      catch(Exception ex) {
          
      }
  }


Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header. This exception occurred in line await _graphClient.Users[UserId].Drive.Items["root"]? You are using client credential flow. Do you grant correct Application type API permissions? By the way, does the file you are trying toupload is a small file?

Thanks Tiny Wang, Yes its a small file and I have correct API permissions also File Read/Write
